chrome does not open in full screen when using --kiosk
I have an application that opens Chrome. I tried using --kiosk but it opens the user selection screen and it doesn't stay in full screen.
I tested the same code to open Firefox and it was successful. It would only be with Chrome, I believe it's because of the user selection screen.
It should open in full screen
void AbrirExecutavel(context, String? executavelPath) {
  if (executavelPath != null && executavelPath.isNotEmpty) {
    try {
      Process.run(executavelPath, ['--kiosk']).then((result) {
        if (result.exitCode != 0) {
          ShowErrorDialog(
            context,
            'Erro: ${result.exitCode}\n'
            'Saída do erro: ${result.stderr}',
          );
        }
      }).catchError((e) {
        ShowErrorDialog(
          context,
          'Erro ao abrir o caminho do executável, verifique se o caminho está correto:\n "$executavelPath"',
        );
      });
    } catch (e) {
      ShowErrorDialog(
        context,
        'Erro ao abrir executável: $e',
      );
    }
  } else {
    ShowErrorDialog(
      context,
      'Caminho do executável não encontrado. \n'
      'Verifique seu arquivo de texto em "C:/mobi_player/caminho_executavel.txt", ele está vazio ou não existe.',
    );
  }
}

